# How to call (or compile) C++ code from Matlab 2016

Tags: c++, matlab, makefile

I'm new with Matlab-C combination and I'm very lost. Any help will be very thankful.
Essentially, what I want is to use a C++ code from a simple matlab script. I've created some variables' values in matlab in order to give them as inputs to the C++ code and then capture theirs output of that C++ code and loading them into matlab.

1. I have a main.cpp and a makefile into the same folder. (they work well)
2. I've created a simple test.m file to create the variables' values for the C++ code and then, recover their outputs.

What I've done is to run the makefile using the mac terminal by typing

`make`

in order to create an executable called "benchmark". Each time I need to change a tiny variable's value from my matlab script, I must go to the terminal again, type

`./benchmark`

and then goes again to the matlab and run the test.m file to update the inputs of the C++ code. As you see, this is not the optimal way to work it.

So I'm wondering how to pass values created in matlab and in the same script updating the ./benchmark executable.

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: User the `mex` API.

Comment: Thank, but when I'm using it in this way:  `mex '/myownpath/makefile'`   it appears something like this:  Error using mex
Unknown file extension ' '     but offcourse, there'snt extention for makefile!!!

Comment: The *best* answer on "how to call or compile C++ code in MATLAB" is use the mex API. Perhaps your question is another one?